# Pass start and end date parameter from text field of access form

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am using MS Access 2016, I am trying to pass start and end date parameter to a query e.g. something like: `=>[start date] & <= [End date]`

What I need is if I leave any date blank e.g. start or end, I required all dates from that start date onward or all dates up until the end date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include an `or is null` branch to your query selection criteria, e.g.:

```
select * from YourTable 
where 
    (YourDate >= Forms![Your Form]![Start Date] or Forms![Your Form]![Start Date] is null) and 
    (YourDate <= Forms![Your Form]![End Date]   or Forms![Your Form]![End Date]   is null)
```